# xcode 7.2 APP.xctest is "red" in color

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am working on a project and I only just realized this but my APP.xctest under the products folder is red. I know that means that Xcode cant find the file but I have never used it and Im not getting any errors so I dont know where to point it to. It might have happened long ago I just happen to come across it recently. I have renamed my project once ( I suspect that this is what caused it but im not sure) Is it safe to delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,it's save to delete them,the file is a target for unit test.if you need it,you can add a new XCTest target again.

[image]

Comment: @C. Wagner...the reason why you see it as red is cause the target file on the system seems to be missing.